# Git command invoked via phing is asking for credentials even though private-public key authentication to git server is in place

Tags: git, public-key-encryption, phing

Public private key authentication has been setup for my user "sandeepan" to access the repository hosted on gitlab. I can run git fetch/pull commands on this server.

However, when I run a fetch command via a phing xml file, I get a prompt to enter the credentials.

. Following is the line which invokes the git fetch -

```
<exec command="git fetch origin test_sandeepan" dir="/home/jenkins/phing/scratchpad/adserver" />
```

I ensured that -

- I am switched to my user "sandeepan".
- Also, the permissions and ownerships of the xml file are as follows -

  -rwxrwxrwx 1 sandeepan sandeepan   6479 Aug  9 08:56 build.xml

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't use phing, but it sounds like it's trying to use the https protocol instead of ssh. Is there a configuration section for the remote url?

Comment: Check if the environment variables are passed to your command.